# Need help to convert python script into ansible modules

Tags: python, ansible

Looking ansible playbook with ansible default modules created in Python.

Python Script

```
txt = "apple ,banana ,cherry ,orange"

x = txt.split(",")

for i in range(len(x)):
    print("fruit" , x[i])
```

Expecting Results with Ansible Modules

```
{"category": "fruit", "name": "apple"},
{"category": "fruit", "name": "banana"},
{"category": "fruit", "name": "cherry"},
{"category": "fruit", "name": "orange"}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```yaml
out: "{{ ['fruit ']|product(txt|split(','))|flatten|join }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
out: fruit apple fruit banana fruit cherry fruit orange
```

Comment: Thanks for that, 

I have corrected my question, Please check